# html frames browser address

Tags: html, frames

I have a question regarding frames.

Say i have a page `frame.html` and it has 2 frames, `menu,html` on the left and `site.html` on the right. The main site will be in the right frame, with the left frame only used for browsing.

The problem is, the web address in the browser. It will always say `frame.html`.

Is there anyway to make it so the web address shows the url of the right frame?

### UPDATE

The actual problem I have is I want there to be a chat frame on the right of my site that doesn't have to reload every page refresh. I can only think of frames to stop it doing this, unless there's another way.

And my site is in php.

Comment: @BalusC — Not so. A build time template engine can solve the problem without any server side processing. It doesn't solve the problem though (now that the question has been updated).

Comment: so you have multiple frames, and you don't want one of them to refresh. why don't you put the refresh script on all of the other frames **except the chat frame**, instead of doing a refresh on the frame container which I assume you're doing.

Comment: nah i dont use frames or anything at the moment, but I want to add a chat to my site but dont want it reloading every page refresh

Comment: Your question states that you are using frames... can you update it to reflect what you have right now and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the address will always be `frame.html`. That's one of the major disadvantages of frames.

Frames became increasing unpopular. They are outdated and even obsolete in HTML5. You should use a `<div>` for the menu instead.

Comment: Frames became so unpopular in the late 90s that "increasingly" isn't really significant :) And HTML 5 doesn't deprecate them (or anything else), it marks them as obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [history api](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) (`pushState` and friends), but that would involve writing quite a lot of JS and has browser support issues.

You would be better off replacing the frames with a template or include system.

I favour [template-toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) (which can be used at build time or run time). PHP is commonly available and has [`include`](http://php.net/include). [SSI](http://bignosebird.com/ssi.shtml) is a classic option.

Answer (score 0):

No. The address shown must be the actual page URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've had to work with frames, but I don't recall there being a way to change from, in your example, frame.html

I would highly recommend avoiding frames, you can accomplish much of the same functionality with CSS styled `<div>`'s nowadays.